# spring integration, how do multiple ssh / switch local user before conencte to remot server

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Can we do something like:

ssh user1@localhost

scp user2@remote:resource/test.txt dest/text.txt

in Spring integration ?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration doesn't do any SSH direct connection. That one is used only for SFTP protocol. And this one is handled by the `DefaultSftpSessionFactory`. For convenience we have a `DelegatingSessionFactory` which may decide which target factory to chose according a provided `key`. Which by default can be stored in the `ThreadLocal`. What you saying looks like a dynamic connection based on the provided user. Probably it can be done as a custom `SessionFactory` implementation which will do a lazy delegation after creating the target factory according provided  credentials.